# How to keep parent element reference while parsing list of children in XML to Object in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Want to keep trak of parent node in child object so that at any point I can go to immidiate parent and access its attributes and also can traverse siblings.

**XML:**

```
<Parent Name"P1">
    <Child Name="C1">
        <GChild Name="GC1"/>
        <GChild  Name="GC2"/>
    </Child>
    <Child Name="C2">
        <GChild  Name="GC3"/>
        <GChild  Name="GC4"/>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

**Class:**

```
[Serializable]
public class Parent
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Child")]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public class Child
    {
        public Parent Parent { get; get;} //Want to know who is its parent.

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GChild")]
        public List<GChild> Children { get; set; }

        public class GChild
        {
            public Child Parent { get; set; } //Want to know who is its parent.

            [XmlAttribute]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Parse:**

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

Created the property named `Parent` of its parent type in all child elements but don't know what to do to assign it. Its `null` for now.
**What changes are needed to be done in object class?**

Comment: You want a table , not nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flat table using Xml Linq.  Creating hierarchical classes makes it harder to get parent/child relationships.  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication124
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Parent Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Child Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("GChild", typeof(string));


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement parent in doc.Descendants("Parent"))
            {
                string parentName = (string)parent.Attribute("Name");
                foreach(XElement child in parent.Elements("Child"))
                {
                    string childName = (string)child.Attribute("Name");
                    foreach (XElement gChild in child.Elements("GChild"))
                    {
                        string gChildStr = (string)gChild.Attribute("Name");

                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { parentName, childName, gChildStr });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create custom collection to hold information about children. When items will be added to this collection you would set Parent property that should be ignored (XmlIgnoreAttribute) when serializeing/deserializing. 
Read [this](https://thomaslevesque.com/2009/06/12/c-parentchild-relationship-and-xml-serialization/). I think it is exactly wnat you search for.